# How to get StackPanel's children to fill maximum space downward?

Tags: wpf, xaml, autolayout, autoresize, dockpanel

I simply want flowing text on the left, and a help box on the right.

The help box should extend all the way to the bottom.

If you take out the outer `StackPanel` below it works great.

But for reasons of layout (I'm inserting UserControls dynamically) I need to have the wrapping `StackPanel`.

How do I get the `GroupBox` to extend down to the bottom of the `StackPanel`, as you can see I've tried:

- `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`
- `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"`
- `Height="Auto"`

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDynamic033.Test3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test3" Height="300" Width="600">
    <StackPanel 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Height="Auto">

        <DockPanel 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Height="Auto" 
            Margin="10">

            <GroupBox 
                DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                Header="Help" 
                Width="100" 
                Background="Beige" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                Height="Auto">
                <TextBlock Text="This is the help that is available on the news screen." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </GroupBox>

            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="Here is the news that should wrap around." TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

### Answer:

Thanks Mark, using `DockPanel` instead of `StackPanel` cleared it up. In general, I find myself using `DockPanel` more and more now for WPF layouting, here's the fixed XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDynamic033.Test3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test3" Height="300" Width="600" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="200">
    <DockPanel 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Height="Auto">

        <DockPanel 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Height="Auto" 
            MinWidth="400"
            Margin="10">

            <GroupBox 
                DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                Header="Help" 
                Width="100" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                Height="Auto">
                <Border CornerRadius="3" Background="Beige">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is the help that is available on the news screen." TextWrapping="Wrap" 

                Padding="5"/>
                </Border>
            </GroupBox>

            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="Here is the news that should wrap around." TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Fixed the formatting - it doesn't like going straight from a list to code

Comment: Can you make a GroupBox stretch that way on its own?  If so, start adding your parent elements one-by-one until you find out which one is breaking the layout.

Comment: RoBorg: nice to know, that had me perplexed, thanks

Comment: Thanks. Using your answer I was able to use 2 nested DockPanels to solve my very similar issue!

Answer (score 395, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `StackPanel` where the final element uses up all the remaining space. But why not use a `DockPanel`? Decorate the other elements in the `DockPanel` with `DockPanel.Dock="Top"`, and then your help control can fill the remaining space.

XAML:

```
<DockPanel Width="200" Height="200" Background="PowderBlue">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Something</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Something else</TextBlock>
    <DockPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Height="Auto" 
        Margin="10">

      <GroupBox 
        DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
        Header="Help" 
        Width="100" 
        Background="Beige" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
        Height="Auto">
        <TextBlock Text="This is the help that is available on the news screen." 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
     </GroupBox>

      <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10" 
           Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
          <TextBlock Text="Here is the news that should wrap around." 
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

If you are on a platform without `DockPanel` available (e.g. WindowsStore), you can create the same effect with a grid. Here's the above example accomplished using grids instead:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200" Background="PowderBlue">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock>Something</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Something else</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GroupBox
            Width="100"
            Height="Auto"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Background="Beige"
            Header="Help">
            <TextBlock Text="This is the help that is available on the news screen." 
              TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <StackPanel Width="Auto" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="Here is the news that should wrap around." 
              TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I've spent the last hour trying to figure out how to get StackPanel to do this. From now on, I'll look here first for my WPF (and other) info.

Comment: I can't believe how much time I've spent trying to get StackPanels to do what I wanted. Thanks for sharing! DockPanels are what I wanted all along.

Comment: There is no dockpanel for tablets it seems. http://www.telerik.com/forums/following-blog-post-and-comparison

Comment: No dock panel for Windows Store apps.

Comment: Now it is all about universal app and universal apps don't support DockPanel yet?

Comment: @yonexbat see my alternative answer with a Grid

Comment: @Dude see the alternative answer with a grid

Comment: yeah I talked about your alternative answer. its not working. GroupBox and DockPanel is the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I couldnt figure out why my datagrid inside of a stack panel was being cut off instead of having a vertical scrollbar.  Use a Dock panel did the trick!

Comment: DockPanels aren't perfect either. If you want the 3rd element to fill the remaining space while the others are fixed, then you have to make some weird manipulations.

Answer (score 116):

The reason that this is happening is because the stack panel measures every child element with positive infinity as the constraint for the axis that it is stacking elements along.  The child controls have to return how big they want to be (positive infinity is not a valid return from the [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx) in either axis) so they return the smallest size where everything will fit.  They have no way of knowing how much space they really have to fill.

If your view doesn’t need to have a scrolling feature and the answer above doesn't suit your needs, I would suggest implement your own panel.  You can probably derive straight from StackPanel and then all you will need to do is change the [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx) method so that it divides the remaining space up between its child elements (giving them each the same amount of extra space).  Elements should render fine if they are given more space than they wanted, but if you give them less you will start to see glitches.

If you want to be able to scroll the whole thing then I am afraid things will be quite a bit more difficult, because the ScrollViewer gives you an infinite amount of space to work with which will put you in the same position as the child elements were originally.  In this situation you might want to create a new property on your new panel which lets you specify the viewport size, you should be able to bind this to the ScrollViewer’s size.  Ideally you would implement [IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx), but that starts to get complicated if you are going to implement all of it properly.

Comment: +1, I would give you more but only 1 is allowed, your first paragraph has pointed out what numerous Microsoft pages have failed to, namely why infinity can occur as a height/width and the fact that you cannot rely on returning availableSize from MeasureOverride.

Comment: A StackPanel inside a Grid solves his rather common need with great ease.  The bottom bit could be put inside a ScrollViewer, if necessary.  I've been doing WPF since 2006 and have only once ever needed to do a custom panel.  I don't think it's a good idea to encourage extra complexity.

Comment: @ChrisBordeman I'm not sure I understand how the stack panel inside the grid solves problem.  The idea is to have one or more child elements in the stack panel stretch to fill the available space.  Putting the stack panel inside a grid doesn't make it do that does it?

Answer (score 73):

An alternative method is to use a Grid with one column and *n* rows.  Set all the rows heights to `Auto`, and the bottom-most row height to `1*`.

I prefer this method because I've found Grids have better layout performance than DockPanels, StackPanels, and WrapPanels.  But unless you're using them in an ItemTemplate (where the layout is being performed for a large number of items), you'll probably never notice.

Comment: for me the best solution. with this it is possible to define more then one growing row

Answer (score 27):

You can use [SpicyTaco.AutoGrid](https://github.com/kmcginnes/SpicyTaco.AutoGrid) - a modified version of `StackPanel`:

```
<st:StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MarginBetweenChildren="10" Margin="10">
   <Button Content="Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" st:StackPanel.Fill="Fill"/>
   <Button Content="Cancel"/>
   <Button Content="Save"/>
</st:StackPanel>
```

First button will be fill.

You can install it via NuGet:

```
Install-Package SpicyTaco.AutoGrid
```

I recommend taking a look at [SpicyTaco.AutoGrid](https://github.com/kmcginnes/SpicyTaco.AutoGrid). It's very useful for forms in WPF instead of `DockPanel`,  `StackPanel` and `Grid` and solve problem with stretching very easy and gracefully. Just look at readme on GitHub.

```
<st:AutoGrid Columns="160,*" ChildMargin="3">
    <Label Content="Name:"/>
    <TextBox/>

    <Label Content="E-Mail:"/>
    <TextBox/>

    <Label Content="Comment:"/>
    <TextBox/>
</st:AutoGrid>
```

Comment: This should be at the top, very useful, thank you very much!

Comment: Don't forget to add xmlns:st="http://schemas.spicytaco.io/"