# How to dock ListView on a StackPanel?

Tags: wpf, listview, stackpanel, dock

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Label Name="Label1" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="Gray" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="28">Window1</Label>               
    <ListView BorderThickness="2,0,2,0" BorderBrush="Gray"Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />                                   
</StackPanel>
```

In the XAML above , I want to dock the `ListView` on the `StackPanel`. I want the `ListView` to take the entire client area of the `StackPanel` after the `Label`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Long story short, the `StackPanel` is not meant to stretch its children, it will just stack them as they come. You want a `DockPanel`. This has been [discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569095/wpf-xaml-how-to-get-stackpanels-children-to-fill-maximum-space-downward).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a DockPanel instead

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
     <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="Label1" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="Gray"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="28">Window1</Label>               
     <ListView BorderThickness="2,0,2,0" BorderBrush="Gray" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
</DockPanel>
```