# controls don't reach right border when aligning right

Tags: wpf, alignment

The right-aligned label doesn't reach the right border:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Label Content="Left Align" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Label Content="Right Align" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</StackPanel>
```

It seems that both labels don't take up full available width even though I've specified HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" . What is the cause of it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `DockPanel` instead of a `StackPanel` for that.

See also [Align items in a stack panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2023201/314334) or

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <Label Content="Left Align" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <Label Content="Right Align" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
</DockPanel>
```

And [@santosc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232551/santosc) described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918982/314334) why the alignment with StackPanel doesn't work as you expected:

> A stackpanel, no matter how you stretch it, will collapse around the
>   children. you can't make it grow more than that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes. But could you please explain me why my XAML doesn't produce same results?

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 when you set the width (of the stackpanel), than its the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `StackPanel` shrinks to fit the content if no width is provided.

Use a `DockPanel`,as Stephan Bauer said, or possibly a `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
     <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Left Align" />
       <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Right Align"  />
    </Grid>
```