# How do I dynamically centre remaining stackpanel elements vertically when I hide items?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Say I have a stackpanel with two text blocks, one on top of the other.  THey are centred horizontally.  But I want to hide one of the text blocks and I want the remaining item to centre vertically according to the remaining space (as if it as the only item).  Is this possible?

```
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" >
                <TextBlock Text="Testing!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="35">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  Text="test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: You can use a Border inside your stackpanel to achieve this. Say `<Stackpanel><Border> ... </Border></Stackpanel>`

Comment: I think you're going to need to give us some of your XAML here to help you out. Normally, if you "hide" something (by setting `Visibility` = `Visibility.Collapsed` the layout will act as if it is not there. So something else must be going on.

Comment: Ok added the xaml.  Well I tried the visibility collapsed option but in the preview window the first textbox doesn't move.  Does it only take effect when I actually view it on the emulator or device? -- EDIT after trying it in the emulator it didn't make a difference.  Visibility collapsed had no effect

Comment: Does it really Veritcally align when both textblocks are visible? As far as I understand the StackPanel will stack things from the top, so both the textblocks should be vertically stacked from the top and the "VerticalAlignment" should not have any effect.

Comment: It seems you're right, vertical alignment doesn't affect the stackpanel items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you can't achieve that with `StackPanel` only, related question : [How can I vertically align a TextBox inside a StackPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918847/how-can-i-vertically-align-a-textbox-inside-a-stackpanel).

Try to wrap your `StackPanel` within a fixed-height container (container with height independent from height of if it's content). Then set `StackPanel`'s `VerticalAlignment` property to `Center` to make it (along with it's content) centered within parent container. For example :

```
<Grid Height="100">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Testing!" FontSize="35"/>
        <TextBlock Text="test"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```