# Fill all available space in StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding_01.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Name="stackPanel1" Width="Auto">        
        <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="Auto" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox2" Width="Auto" />
        <Button Content="Button" Name="button1" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I want the Button fill all available space on the StackPanel. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get StackPanel's children to fill maximum space downward?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569095/how-to-get-stackpanels-children-to-fill-maximum-space-downward)

Comment: (Seriously, that's the very first question in the related section, you should see that even *before* posting; third suggestion would work as well (along with probably even more))

Comment: I read that question. It sounds like it describes a situation where you want a horizontally oriented stackpanel to fill all vertical space. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you mean fill all horizontal and vertical space you should use a DockPanel.

```
    <DockPanel Height="Auto" Name="stackPanel1" Width="Auto" LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="Auto" />
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="23" Name="textBox2" Width="Auto" />
        <Button Content="Button" Name="button1" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: No more dockPanel on Windows Store Apps :(

Comment: @Teomanshipahi You can try to use a `Grid` with `Rowdefinitions`