# StrechToFit in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I want to arrange two UIControls vertically. The top one is variable height while the bottom one is fixed height. How can I make the top element stretch to available height in a StackPanel or Grid?

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341940/fill-all-available-space-in-stackpanel), and the answer suggested the use of DockPanel, however in WP8 there's no DockPanel, so is there any other alternative of that?

Comment: You can accomplish this using Grid panel, but not using StackPanel. There is a good article about how to layout UIControls inside a Grid panel [here](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html)

Comment: @har07 Thanks for suggesting this. I am going to check this in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Grid can do that with a row-height of "*" - i.e. a Grid with two rows, the top one "*" the bottom one "auto" would do the trick (not verified for Win8 but should work if memory serves)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```